# Foreign key to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating a database for storing user data and repeated data for each user (for example if it was for running it might have distance, time, date, etc. for each run). The users are all in one table

```sql
CREATE TABLE users ( name varchar(30), id int primary key );
```

Each user will submit data that needs to be put into a different table (schema doesn't matter here). I could either make this set of data into one big table wiht all the submitted data plus a key to the user

```sql
CREATE TABLE data ( ..., user_id int REFERENCES users );
```

or my prefered way which would be have one table per user and have each entry in the `users` table somehow refence the whole table for that user. I'm not quite sure how you'd do this and can't find any way to do so so far.

Any help is very appreciated thanks.

Comment: That looks good, except that `user` is a reserved keyword and will require quoting. Better use `user_id` in the `data` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to use one table for all users data, just add index on field user_id:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( name varchar(30), id int primary key );

CREATE TABLE data ( 
    --- ..., 
    user_id int REFERENCES users (id)
);

CREATE INDEX data_user_id_ix ON data(user_id);
```

https://sqlize.online/sql/psql11/44a7c7e8145db1e0583f8c91025da72f/